# In python sqlite3, why wildcard doesn't work in this case?

Tags: python, sqlite, wildcard, sql-like

I don't know why the following code cannot select any row where: term = 'apple' in table wordcount

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM wordcount WHERE term LIKE '[a]%'")
```

Here's the tutorial in wc3school

Using the SQL [charlist] Wildcard
The following SQL statement selects all customers with a City starting with "b", "s", or "p":

SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City LIKE '[bsp]%';

Anybody have clue?

Comment: Refer to http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html - notice the distinct lack of "[" or "]" in the discussion of the LIKE operator.

Answer (score 3):

Simply "a%", not "[a]%". Maybe you were thinking of regexp kind of syntax, but this is different.